# Is there a way to use django url template in json_script?

Tags: django

trying to find a way to save a url into a json script but its not rendering and reading it literally unlike other values:

Tried this way

```
{{ "{% url 'tutorhomepage:tutorSelectedDay' tutor_id selected_date%}" | json_script:"url_test"}}
```

And this way:

```
{{ url_test | json_script:"{% url 'tutorhomepage:tutorSelectedDay' tutor_id selected_date%}"}}
```

But still comes out like this:

```
<script id="url_test" type="application/json">"{% url 'tutorhomepage:tutorSelectedDay' tutor_id selected_date%}"</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store this in a variable:

```
{% url 'tutorhomepage:tutorSelectedDay' tutor_id selected_date as myurl %}
{{ myurl|json_script:"url_test" }}
```

Comment: thanks willem for the help